# Psql Hint Does not makes any sense

Tags: python, postgresql

My python code for updating a table is something like this:-

```
def reportMatch(winner, loser):
    """Records the outcome of a single match between two players.

    Args:
      winner:  the id number of the player who won
      loser:  the id number of the player who lost
    """
    conn=connect()
    cur=conn.cursor()
    sql="UPDATE players SET wins = wins + 1 WHERE id = winner;"
    cur.execute(sql)
    sql="UPDATE players SET losses = losses + 1 WHERE id = loser;"
    cur.execute(sql)
    sql="INSERT INTO matches (player_a,player_b,result) VALUES (%s,%s,%s);"
    data=(winner,loser,winner)
    cur.execute(sql,data)
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return
```

What it is doing is that it is updating the table of matches and players which are like follows:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS players CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE players(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    pl_name TEXT,
    wins INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    losses INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    draws INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    matches INTEGER DEFAULT 0
        );

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS matches CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE matches(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    pl_a INTEGER REFERENCES players(id),
    pl_b INTEGER REFERENCES players(id),
    result INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
        );
```

Now when I run this the aforementioned function the error that I get is :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tournament_test.py", line 153, in <module>
    testReportMatches()
  File "tournament_test.py", line 84, in testReportMatches
    reportMatch(id1, id2)
  File "/vagrant/tournament/tournament.py", line 99, in reportMatch
    cur.execute(sql)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "winner" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE players SET wins = wins + 1 WHERE id = winner;
                                                      ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "players.wins".
```

I am stuck at this point where I dont know how to compare the 'id' with the 'id' that I am receiving in the variable 'winner'

I only want to update the rows where the id matches the winners id. I am new to this so sorry for such lame questions but I am picking up pace at learning. Please Help, Thank You.

Comment: whats the table def for `players` look like?

Comment: I think you're talking about the players table. I have provided with that in the question.

Comment: What kind of error do you get if you try: `sql = "UPDATE players SET wins = wins + 1 WHERE id = %s;" % str(winner)` (and do the same with the loser statement) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a python variable in a SQL query, you can make the relevant part of the query a parameter with `%s`:

```
sql = "UPDATE players SET wins = wins + 1 WHERE id = %s;"
```

When you execute it, pass the parameter as a tuple argument to the execute method:

```
cur.execute(sql, (winner,))
```

Comment: It is still giving me this:--- psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: UPDATE players SET wins = wins + 1 WHERE id = %s;